# How can I require an array of resources in puppet?

Tags: puppet

In my Puppet-manifest I need to exec a command, but only after an array-driven *collection* of another exec finished. Like this (pseudo-code):

```
  define foo() {
    exec { "touch $name": }
  }

....
  {
    $bars = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
    foo { $bars : }
    exec { "echo Done" :
        require => [ Foo["a"], Foo["b"], Foo["c"] ]
    }
  }
```

How do I implement the same dependency as given above without repeating each element of list `$bars` by hand?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, never mind... The same array of arguments can be used, apparently:

```
$bars = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
foo { $bars : }
exec { "echo Done" :
    require => [ Foo[$bars] ]
}
```